# AJAX Control Toolkit issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been given an application's binaries which has been written in ASPX and C# (using .NET 2). Our task is to deploy it on our server. We have managed to set it up on the server but we get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The line in web.config which has been highlighted reads as follows:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

The server has .NET 2 framework installed and we're using a Win2003 server box with IIS 6.0. Unfortunatelly, we have limited experience in .NET as our main platform is in Java and we don't have a Visual Studio available. All we want to do is deploy the application.

Can anyone provide some help on how to surpass this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [AJAX Extensions](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=77296) installed on the machine?

Comment: In the server we didn't install anything else apart from .NET 2. However, within the application itself there is a bin folder which includes the file: AJAXControlToolkit.dll

Comment: As you are trying to use System.Web.Extensions you need to install the above file.